# How to fetch past events using Google Calendar API in Android?

Tags: android

**Explanation:** I created one demo and I'm successfully able to create and fetch all future events. But I want to fetch past events as well.

I won't include all code, but I can say that I followed exactly this (https://kpblogs.com/2016/11/02/how-to-integrate-google-calendar-api-in-android-application/) Post and code also there if someone want to import whole project.

Now, I'll post the main part here, because other are just model class and Google auth required, permissions n all, that you can check in that above post link:

```
private void getDataFromApi() {
            try {
                // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
                DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
                com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                        .setMaxResults(10)
                        .setTimeMin(now)
                        .setOrderBy("startTime")
                        .setSingleEvents(true)
                        .execute();
                showLog("WHAT: " + events);
                List<Event> items = events.getItems();
                Events scheduledEvents;
                eventsList.clear();
                for (Event event : items) {
                    DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
                    if (start == null) {
                        start = event.getStart().getDate();
                    }
                    scheduledEvents = new Events();
                    scheduledEvents.setEventId(event.getId());
                    showLog("ID: " + event.getId());
                    scheduledEvents.setDescription(event.getDescription());
                    scheduledEvents.setEventSummery(event.getSummary());
                    scheduledEvents.setLocation(event.getLocation());
                    scheduledEvents.setStartDate(start.toString());
                    scheduledEvents.setEndDate("");
                    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                    if (event.getAttendees() != null) {
                        for (EventAttendee eventAttendee : event.getAttendees()) {
                            if (eventAttendee.getEmail() != null)
                                stringBuffer.append(eventAttendee.getEmail() + "       ");
                        }
                        scheduledEvents.setAttendees(stringBuffer.toString());
                    } else {
                        scheduledEvents.setAttendees("");
                    }
                    eventsList.add(scheduledEvents);
                    eventStrings.add(
                            String.format("%s (%s)", event.getSummary(), start));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

---

Something should be there from this below property to fecch past events:

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                        .setMaxResults(50)
                        .setTimeMin(now)
                        .setOrderBy("startTime")
                        .setSingleEvents(true)
                        .execute();
```

Before posting this answer, I tried to search on Google, Stack Overflow and that blog comments from where I got code, but I'm not able to understand that for which properties I have to change to get solution.

Comment: It's not clear what you've already tried to solve the problem you're facing. A good place to start would be to find the documentation for the Calendar API and figure out which methods can give you the data you're looking for.

Comment: @Egor I'm able to fetch future Events from Google Calendar API, but not Past events.I read the documentation but it's not mentioned. And I tried to search everywhere in Google and Stack overflow, but not able to find it. So I posted a question here. Can you help me?

Comment: I never worked with Calendar API, but just by reading the docs I discovered `Calendar.Events.List.setTimeMax()`, which might be what you're looking for: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/Calendar.Events.List.html#setTimeMax-com.google.api.client.util.DateTime-

Comment: @Egor Thanks for replying. Let me check

Comment: @Egor not setTimeMax but setTimeMin. Thanks it's working. Please post an answer, I want to accept

Comment: @Egor Can you please please pease help me here:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661282/why-does-event-dalation-is-getting-404-from-google-calendar-api-even-though-im    I feel you intelligent person, without any experienced you provide me solution. Thanks dear